# Crontab GitHub push won't recognize credentials

Tags: git, github, cron

I have a crontab script to push some files to git. I use github desktop and it created my directory on my M1 MacOs computer. 
Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Users/me/Documents/GitHub/myUsername.github.io
git add -A
git commit -m "Daily update."
git push
```

The script works just fine when I run it from terminal but when I run it via chron I get the message

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured

How can I run this from crontab and have it successfully push?

Comment: Side note: Git doesn't push *files*, it pushes *commits* (which then contain files and that's probably what you care about here, but it's something to keep in mind). More directly related: macOS cron has both "user cron jobs" and "system cron jobs"; make sure you're doing a user one. Consider using ssh authentication rather than https authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the process runs as root from `cron`.

If so, it would not access the same `git config --global credential.helper` setting (which is set in `/home/myuser`, not `/root`)

Make sure your [crontab file uses the username field](https://serverfault.com/a/352837/783) in order to execute the command as you, not as root.

The OP confirms:

- the process is runs as the user account
- there is no credential helper.

Recommendation:

- [install GCM](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager#download-and-install), the cross-platform Git Credential Manager from Microsoft
- register your `github.com` credentials (GitHub user account / token)

That is:

`printf "host=github.com\nprotcol=https\nusername=MyGitHubAccount\npassword=myGitHubToken" | git credential-manager-core store`

This assumes the git-credential-manager-core executable installed with GCM is in your `$PATH`.

That way, no more "`could not read Username`" on the next `git push`.

---

The [OP Sparkles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11471235/sparkles) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249959/crontab-github-push-wont-recognize-credentials/72250012#comment127751152_72250012):

> It turned out I do think homebrew was affecting things because after getting rid of it it all seemed to work.